# Ratelimit the number of pods created every second in a deployment

Tags: kubernetes, scale, rate-limiting

I am using Kubernetes to create a deployment with 1000s of small clients. However, my server that these clients connect to cannot handle so many requests at once. Does anyone know a way in Kubernetes to only create 100 pods per minute, wait for them to in ready state and then create the next 100.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such direct option in K8s 1.18. Here is related [github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/3312). Some possible workarounds are:

- use multiple deployments, maybe within multiple namespaces. It may be hard to manage single deployment with 1000s of replicas in therms of any changes.
- implement random configurable delay inside your client(or with lightweight wrapper) to spread the load over time, depending on total wall clock startup time of your 1000s clients and server power
- implement [custom metrics agent](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#support-for-custom-metrics) with `pod is ready` check to scale deployment with [HorisontalPodAutoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) as you need and use [Scaling Policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#scaling-policies) to create 100 pods per minute
- implement your own pod autoscaler